# Why is object query parameter null?

Tags: java, spring, rest, query-string, openapi

I describe a path in openapi file in my spring boot application.
Openapi generates by the file api class which handles http requests.
Also I use swagger which hepls construct a valid url, where I can put query parameters as well.
I'm wondering, why having all this generated staff I receive null object instead of expected.

part of api.yaml

```
/films:
    get:
      summary: Отфильтрованные фильмы
      operationId: findFilms
      tags: [selections]
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: filter
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              genreId:
                type: integer
              year:
                type: integer
              countryId:
                type: integer
          style: deepObject
          explode: false
      responses:
        200:
          description: successfull response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: 'list-schemas.yaml#/components/schemas/SelectionTo'
```

generated java class

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen")

@Validated
@Api(value = "Selections")
public interface SelectionsApi {

    default Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Отфильтрованные фильмы", nickname = "findFilms", , response = SelectionTo.class, tags={ "selections", })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "successful response", response = SelectionTo.class) })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/films",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
    default ResponseEntity<SelectionTo> _findFilms(@ApiParam() @Valid @RequestParam(value = "filter", required = false) Filter filter) {
        return findFilms(filter);
    }

    // Override this method
    default ResponseEntity<SelectionTo> findFilms(Filter filter) {
        getRequest().ifPresent(request -> {
            ...
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }
```

generated query parameter class

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen")

public class Filter   {
  @JsonProperty("genreId")
  private Integer genreId = null;

  @JsonProperty("year")
  private Integer year = null;

  @JsonProperty("countryId")
  private Integer countryId = null;

  public Filter genreId(Integer genreId) {
    this.genreId = genreId;
    return this;
  }
```

implementing interface

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<SelectionTo> findFilms(Filter filterType) {
        //here filter is null !
        return ResponseEntity.ok(transformer.transform(service.getItemsInfo()));
    }
```

request

```
http://localhost/films?filter[genreId]=13&filter[year]=2021
```

How openapi file could be improved? Because this is the only thing I've defined. Or what else could the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, Spring MVC does not support decoding nested object query parameters in the OpenAPI `deepObject` style, like `filter[genreId]=13`, at least out of the box.

Comment: yes, as far as I can remember that was true, no support for deepObject in this sense, we used that time query naming "filter[genreId]=" so it was not super cool but enough for our purpose) thanks for reply)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `@RequestParam()` from filter object.

Like this:

```
default ResponseEntity<SelectionTo> _findFilms(@ApiParam() @Valid Filter filter) {
    return findFilms(filter);
}
```

Also the request should be http://localhost/films?genreId=13&year=2021

Comment: *"Also the request should be http://localhost/films?genreId=13&year=2021"* - No, [`deepObject`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#style-examples) corresponds to `?filter[genreId]=13&filter[year]=2021`.

Comment: @Helen what do you suggest then?

Comment: Thanks!

Though these parameters in query were desirable in that way filter[genreId]=1&filter[year]=2000&filter[somewhat]=val

And @RequestParam(...) - is generated, I'm not very interested in removing it every time. Is there any possibility to tune openapi to generate code without that annotation?